# Where to check for null, in calling method or in function?

Tags: null

Should a check for null occur before making the call to a function or within the function itself?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706263/where-to-check-if-an-object-is-null-or-not

Answer (score 7):

I would say within the call itself. That way, you only check for null in one place, not 5 places if you call that function from 5 different spots.

But this isn't a for sure answer. It really depends on the function and what the consequences are of calling it with a null argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use the object later on you should check **Before** making the call to the function, It will **avoid an exception** in the long run, but it really matters ***when the object is used***

Answer (score 1):

Always code defensively. Do both, but the callee is more important.

Answer (score 1):

If receiving a null on a function is a valid possibility, check for null within the function. Also DRY, and avoid having to check for null multiple times in the callers (so I second ryeguy's answer).

If receiving a null represents an error, fail (and fail early) with an exception (or let something like NullPointerException happen naturally).

If the exception occurs try to figure out why, and either: (i) remove the cause of the problem; or (ii) handle the exception properly