# How to check if an object is defined?

Tags: c#

I would like to check if an object is defined or exists using C#.

Something like this:

```
if (defined(Object)){

}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please?Do you mean not null?

Comment: Do you want to know if an object has been initialized ? if so you can just use if (SomeObject != null). Otherwise, please provide more information

Comment: an unexecutable function. what an odd concept.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You check if it's `null` in C# like this:

```
if(MyObject != null) {
  //do something
}
```

If you want to check against default (tough to understand the question on the info given) check:

```
if(MyObject != default(MyObject)) {
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If a class type is not defined, you'll get a compiler error if you try to use the class, so in that sense you should have to check.

If you have an instance, and you want to ensure it's not null, simply check for null:

```
if (value != null)
{
    // it's not null. 
}
```