# c# possible to check if a var is defined?

Tags: c#

I have a question: I need to check if a variable is defined in C#. I don't want to check if it is null because then I want to make this, it must exist.

e.g. I need to know it the variable `string foo` is defined. Is there anything like:

```
isDefined("foo") :: bool
```

Comment: Perhaps you could describe your real problem? Why do you want to check existence of a local variable? Doesn't make any sense at all IMO.

Comment: Do you mean something what is possible in a language without the necessity to declare every variable like JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if an object is defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537987/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-defined)

Answer (score 9):

As you know the variable is a `string`, you could use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo)`.  This returns a `bool`.

If you aren't sure what type the variable is, you could use: `if (foo != null)`

Comment: This is NOT what OP asked for... "defined" != "initialized"

Answer (score 3):

Can you elaborate on how you intend to use this? Based on this question and one of your previous questions, it looks like you are coming from a PHP background. In C#, there is no notion of an undefined variable. At any point in the code, a given variable is either declared or not, and you can determine whether it is declared or not simply by looking at the code. If it is not declared, the compiler will not let you use the variable at all (it doesn't exist). A variable may be declared, but uninitialized; however, the compiler will not let you read the value of the variable unless it is certain that the variable has a value. For instance:

```
int foo; // Declared, but uninitialized
if (bar == 42)
    foo = 3; // Initialize foo
// At this point, foo may or may not be initialized.
// Since we cannot be sure that it is initialized, 
// the next line will not compile.
x = foo;
```

If you want to keep track of whether or not a variable has been assigned a value (and you cannot use `null` to indicate that no value has been assigned), you need to keep track of this with a separate `bool` variable that starts out as `false` and is set to `true` when you assign to the other variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access local variables by their name at runtime. To access members by name at runtime you can use reflection and `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is very old, I was facing the same need. After a little research I understood that either our definition of the issue is not clear or there isn't much support on this case. In my code I did a *workaround* with a ***try / catch*** block assuming that if the variable is not defined inside my class then at the moment when I try to access it it will drop an *Exception*. If exception present then I address the flow in the catch part.

The CustomLabel is a variable in a object that is being parsed in a loop. Please for the sake of simplicity assume the below example just with the main focus.

Example:

```
//startingDate
                    try
                    {
                        startYear = DateTime.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(relationshipDetail.startingDate) ? "" : relationshipDetail.startingDate).Year;
                    }
                    catch (Exception statYeareX)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(statYeareX.Message.ToString());
                        //when is issing a starting year
                        startYear = 0;
                    }
```

Before it was only `this.startYear = DateTime.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(relationshipDetail.startingDate) ? "" : relationshipDetail.startingDate).Year;`  and it worked ok under QA and initial testing because the variable was defined but not initialised and thus not assigned a value. When it went into production and the parsing of the JSON -> Object started happening we saw that there were ***null reference exceptions*** due to the variable not being present at all in the initial JSON.

Answer (score 1):

First, declare the object with `null` value
example:

```
TextBox tx = null;
```

Then in the same context, you can check if the object is null to assign its type. Example:

```
if(tx ==null) tx = new TextBox();
```

Note: this is very useful when you are doing recursive calls to the method.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use This Method:

```cs
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(foo) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo)) {
         Console.WriteLine("Empty")
    }
```

> String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) Checks If A String Is Null Or Made Of White Spaces

> String.IsNullOrEmpty(String) Checks If A String Is Null Or Empty

Comment: Answer without explanation are considered bad practise and open up the potential for less experienced users implementing poor / dangerous code. Providing explanations also allows less experienced users to better understand what the given solution is doing and how it does it.

Comment: I don't think this adds anything the top answer doesn't already say. The top answer is also wrong. OP says, "I don't want to check if it is null".

Comment: This Will Check If The String Is Null, Empty Or Make Only Of White Spaces