# Should we always check each parameter of method in java for null in the first line?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, null, validation

Every method accepts a set of parameter values. Should we always validate the non-nullness of input parameters or allow the code to fail with classic `RunTimeException`?

I have seen a lot of code where people don't really check the nullness of input parameters and just write the business logic using the parameters. What is the best way?

```
void public( String a, Integer b, Object c)
{
  if( a == null || b == null || c == null)
  {
    throw new RunTimeException("Message...");
  }
  .....business logic.....
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to check if an object is null or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706263/where-to-check-if-an-object-is-null-or-not)

Comment: The other question is about `.net` but is in essence identical.

Comment: None of the current answers mention the use of annotations and static analysis, such as FindBugs @NonNull, @CheckForNull, etc. Also, although this is not a duplicate of the .Net question above, it's likely been covered at least once in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The best way is to **only check when necessary**.

If your method is `private`, for example, so you know nobody else is using it, and you know you aren't passing in any nulls, then no point to check again.

If your method is `public` though, who knows what users of your API will try and do, so better check.

If **in doubt, check**.

If the best you can do, however, is throw a `NullPointerException`, then may not want to check. For example:

```
int getStringLength(String str) {
  return str.length();
}
```

Even if you checked for `null`, a reasonable option would be throwing a `NullPointerException`, which `str.length()` will do for you anyways.

Comment: I would not recommend relying on automatic NullPointerException in place of explicit argument validation. Two reasons: (a) validation should always happen as early as possible (think method changing some state before encountering NPE) and (b) code supportability. An NPE in the body of class X will first go to owner of class X as it appears like a bug in implementation. If, however, you explicitly check args for null and throw say IllegalArgumentException (also RuntimeException like NPE), then it will be obvious that the problem is with caller of class X.

Answer (score 6):

No. It's  standard to assume that parameters will not be null and that a NullPointerException will be thrown otherwise. If your method allows a parameter to be null, you should state that in your api.

Answer (score 3):

It's an unfortunate aspect of Java that references can be `null` and there is no way to specify in the language that they are not.

So generally yes, don't make up an interpretation for `null` and don't get into a situation where an NPE might be thrown later.

JSR305 (now inactive) allowed you to annotate parameters to state that they should not be given `null`s.

```
void fn(@Nonnull String a, @Nonnull Integer b, @Nonnull Object c) {
```

Verbose, but that's Java for you. There are other annotation libraries and checkers that do much the same, but are non-standard.

(Note about capitalisation: When camel-casing words of the form "non-thing", the [standard](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index-files/index-14.html) is not to capitalise the route word unless it is the name of a class. So `nonthing` and `nonnull`.)

Annotations also don't actually enforce the rule, other than when a checker is run. You can statically include a method to do the checking:

```
public static <T> T nonnull(T value) {
    if (value == null) {
        throwNPE();
    }
    return value;
}
private static void throwNPE() {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

Returning the value is handy in constructors:

```
import static pkg.Check.nonnull;

class MyClass {
    @Nonnull private final String thing;
    public MyClass(@Nonnull String thing) {
        this.thing = nonnull(thing);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I think annotations are great. And this implementation looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a great deal of point in doing this.  You're simply replicating behaviour that you'd get for free the first time you try to operate on `a`, `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you expect any of your arguments to be `null` - more precisely, if your method can still make a correct decision if some parameters are `null`.

If not, it's good practice to check for `null` and raise an exception, because otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException`, which you should never catch, as its appearance always indicates that you forgot to check your variables in your code. (and if you catch it, you might miss other occurrences of it being thrown, and you may introduce bugs).

On the other hand, if you throw `RunTimeException` or some other custom exception, you could then handle it somewhere on the upstream, so that you have more control over what goes on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, public methods should scrub the input, especially if bad input could cause problems within your method's code.  It's a good idea to fail fast; that is, check as soon as possible.  Java 7 added a new `Objects` class that makes it easy to check for null parameters and include a customized message:

```
public final void doSomething(String s)
{
  Objects.requireNonNull(s, "The input String cannot be null");
  // rest of your code goes here...
}
```

This will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Javadocs for the `Objects` class:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your code is trying to do and the situation in which you want to throw an `Exception`. Sometime you will want your method to always throw an Exception if your method will not be able to work properly with null values. If your method can work around null values then its probably not necessary to throw an Exception.

Adding too many checked Exceptions can make for very convoluted and complicated code. This was the reason that they were not included in C#.

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't do that universally.

My preferences, in order, would be:

1. Do something sensible with the null. The sensible thing to do depends entirely on the situation, but throwing a custom exception should not be your first choice.
2. Use an assertion to check for null and test thoroughly, eliminating any situations in which null input is produced since - a.k.a bugs.
3. For public APIs, document that null isn't allowed and let it fail with an NPE.

Comment: @downvoter No explanation? Just don't like the cut of my jib?

Answer (score 0):

You should never throw a runtime exception unless it is truly a fatal condition for the operation of the system, such as missing critical runtime parameters, but even then this is questionable as the system should just not start.

What are the business rules? Is null allowed for the field? Is it not?

In any case, it is always good practice to CHECK for nulls on ANY parameters passed in before you attempt to operate on them, so you don't get `NullPointerExceptions` when someone passes you bad data.

Answer (score -6):

If you don't know whether you should do it, the chances are, you don't need to do it.

JDK sources, and Joshua Bloch's book, are *terrible* examples to follow, because they are targeting *very* different audiences. How many of us are writing public APIs for millions of programmers?